# How to override JSON property name of file property generated by FluentValidation in ASP .Net Core?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, fluentvalidation

I'm trying to validate file size using FluentValidation in ASP.Net Core 3.1, and it works properly, but the property name generated looks like this:

```
 {
  "type": "https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.1",
  "title": "One or more validation errors occurred.",
  "status": 400,
  "traceId": "|f885b78f-4a52ff23c676c331.",
  "errors": {
    "MyFile.Length": [
      "My file: The max file size allowed is 5 Mb."
    ]
  }
}
```

The problem is that property name generated is `"MyFile.Length"` and I would like that the result was only `"MyFile"`. My current code is:

**InsertMovementValidator.cs**

```
public class InsertMovementValidator : AbstractValidator<InsertMovementDTO>
{
    public InsertMovementValidator ()
    {
        RuleFor(x => x.MyFile).SetValidator(new FileValidator());
    }
}
```

**FileValidator.cs**

```
public class FileValidator : AbstractValidator<IFormFile>
{
    public FileValidator()
    {
        RuleFor(x => x.Length).LessThanOrEqualTo(5242880) //5 Megabytes
            .WithName("My file")
            .WithMessage("{PropertyName}: The max file size allowed is 5 Mb");
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Probably you should use ```WithName``` in your validator ```InsertMovementValidator```.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the Validator like below:

```
public class InsertMovementValidator : AbstractValidator<InsertMovement>
{
    public InsertMovementValidator()
    {
        
        RuleFor(x => x.MyFile).SetValidator(new FileValidator()).OverridePropertyName(""); 
    }
}

public class FileValidator : AbstractValidator<IFormFile>
{
    public FileValidator()
    {
        RuleFor(x => x.Length).LessThanOrEqualTo(102400) //100 kb
            .OverridePropertyName("My file")
            .WithName("My file")
            .WithMessage("{PropertyName}: The max file size allowed is 100 Kb");
    }
}
```

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can also set configuration in one place instead of writing for every single DTOs fields. (in Program.cs )

Following code will work for you :

```
FluentValidation.ValidatorOptions.Global.PropertyNameResolver = (type, member, expression) => member?.Name; // you can return whatever string object you want
```

you can also change the display name with this option:

```
FluentValidation.ValidatorOptions.Global.DisplayNameResolver = (type, member, expression) => $"{member?.Name}: "; // you can return whatever string object you want
```